# ACLs not supported on at least one file system: Distcp HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, distcp

```
 As per distcp documentation -> 
If -pa is specified, DistCp preserves the permissions also because 
ACLs are a super-set of permissions.
```

```
but hadoop distcp -pa -delete -update /src/path /dest/path/
is failing with ACLs not supported on at least one file system.
Complete logs below
```

The above command executed is failing.
Expectation is to copy hdfs file from source to destination with ACL .

org.apache.hadoop.tools.CopyListing$AclsNotSupportedException: ACLs not supported for file system: hdfs://10.20.0.7:8020
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.util.DistCpUtils.checkFileSystemAclSupport(DistCpUtils.java:381)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.configureOutputFormat(DistCp.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createJob(DistCp.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createAndSubmitJob(DistCp.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:462)

Comment: Below updated command reserves the ACL
` hadoop distcp -pugp /src  /dest    `
The full command used for replicating the hdfs directory is
` hadoop distcp -pugp -delete -update /src / dest `

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop distcp -D ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true hdfs://<insecure_hdp>/test01.txt hdfs://<secure_hdp>/user/hdfs
```

Make sure to run this command from the secure cluster if you have any.

OR

Set the following value in your `core-site.xml` and try again:

```
<property> 
  <name>ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed</name>
  <value>true</value>  
</property>
```